# Getting value from the custom nav bar

Tags: javascript, return-value

I'm working on the web page where I want to filter products by taking values from the nav bar using JS, like this:

```
<nav id="shop-nav" class="nav">
        <li> value="1">Something</li>
        <li> value="2">Something</li>
        <li> value="3">Something</li>
        <li> value="4">Something</li>
    </nav>
```

My JS code is:

```
for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    const link = document.createElement('li')
    link.innerHTML = categories[i].name
    link.value = categories[i].id
    nav.appendChild(link)
}
```

I know that this is possible with `<select></select>` tag, but I want to do it with the custom nav bar.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code you provided and there is an error having to do with categories. Where is categories coming from? Thanks!

Also, I made a small update in the HTML, below.

> Blockquote Uncaught ReferenceError: categories is not defined

```js
for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    const link = document.createElement('li')
    link.innerHTML = categories[i].name
    link.value = categories[i].id
    nav.appendChild(link)
}
```

```html
<nav id="shop-nav" class="nav">
        <li value="1">Something</li>
        <li value="2">Something</li>
        <li value="3">Something</li>
        <li value="4">Something</li>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I forgot to wrote it, my categories are in json file. This works fine with the select tag where I get values from the options. I just wanted to do something different

Comment: This is my function with `<select><select/>`  tag: `select.addEventListener ('change', filterProducts)

async function filterProducts () {
    const categoryId = select.value
    console.log(categoryId)
    
    const filteredProducts = products.filter (product => product.categoryId == categoryId)
    showProducts (filteredProducts)

    if (select.value == 'default') {
        showProducts (products)
    }
}` and showProducts() is my function to get all the products from json.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding please correct me if I am. But if you want to get the values from the navbar, you can use queryselector.

```
let navBarChildren = document.querySelector("nav[id='shop-nav']").children
```